# Formatting floating point number as mixed fractional in Ruby

Tags: ruby, formatting

I have to format numbers that are either whole numbers or mixed fractional numbers with quarters (1/4, 1/2, 3/4) or thirds (1/3, 2/3).

The numbers are given as floats, for example `1.3333333` or `1.5` and are therefore inaccurate (but always close to a quarter or a third).

The formatting method is supposed to return Unicode fractions, for example:

```
1.0    #=> 1
1.3333 #=> 1⅓
1.5    #=> 1½
1.6667 #=> 1⅔
```

My current approach is to format the number via `sprintf` and to apply a second formatting based on the result:

```
def format_fraction(number)
  fix, frac = sprintf('%0.2f', number).split('.')
  case frac
  when '00' then "#{fix}"
  when '25' then "#{fix}¼"
  when '33' then "#{fix}⅓"
  when '50' then "#{fix}½"
  when '67' then "#{fix}⅔"
  when '75' then "#{fix}¾"
  end
end
```

Is there a better / less string-based / more numeric way to solve this?

Comment: Do you need to support only quarters and thirds?  In any case, I think your current solution is pretty good.  Ideally, you'd be using rationals instead of floats, but it seems you don't control that part

Comment: You could start with something like: `fix, frac = number.rationalize(0.1).divmod(1)` but I'm not sure that would make your code shorter unless you add a method to the `Rational` class.

Comment: @Jonah yes, it's only quarters and thirds. The values come from a JSON API with SQL backend. I could request a change on that part, but if I'm not mistaken, neither JSON nor SQL have a rational type. Besides, how would I turn `4/3r` into `"1⅓"` in Ruby?

Comment: @Stefan, well you could just do your matching using `==` instead of the string stuff if you were working with rationals.  But it's hardly worth a backend change.  Your current solution is exactly what I'd do here.

Comment: @MarcRohloff I think it has to be `rationalize(0.01)`, but that is indeed a good suggestion! I wasn't aware of that argument.

Answer (score 3):

*[Answering my own question here]*

Following [Marc Rohloff's suggestion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/175945/formatting-floating-point-number-as-mixed-fractional-in-ruby#comment333844_175945), I'm using [`Float#rationalize`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Float.html#method-i-rationalize) with an argument of `0.01` to convert the floats to rational numbers:

```
1.0.rationalize(0.01)
#=> (1/1)

1.3333.rationalize(0.01)
#=> (4/3)

1.5.rationalize(0.01)
#=> (3/2)

1.6666.rationalize(0.01)
#=> (5/3)
```

`divmod` can then be used to get the fixed and fractional part:

```
(5/3r).divmod(1)
#=> [1, (2/3)]
```

Applied to my method:

```
def format_fraction(number)
  fix, frac = number.rationalize(0.01).divmod(1)
  case frac
  when 0/1r then "#{fix}"
  when 1/4r then "#{fix}¼"
  when 1/3r then "#{fix}⅓"
  when 1/2r then "#{fix}½"
  when 2/3r then "#{fix}⅔"
  when 3/4r then "#{fix}¾"
  end
end

format_fraction(1.0)    #=> "1"
format_fraction(1.3333) #=> "1⅓"
format_fraction(1.5)    #=> "1½"
format_fraction(1.6666) #=> "1⅔"
```

It's not a huge change, but the `when` arguments now resemble the output more closely, which makes the code easier to understand IMO.

The method could be further shortened by extracting the rational => string pairs:

```
FRACTIONS = { 1/4r => '¼', 1/3r => '⅓', 1/2r => '½', 2/3r => '⅔', 3/4r => '¾' }

def format_fraction(number)
  fix, frac = number.rationalize(0.01).divmod(1)
  [fix, FRACTIONS[frac]].join
end
```

Comment: I like the last version, it would make it easier to add representations later. It might be worth adding a fallback though, just in case.

Comment: @MarcRohloff I could use `FRACTIONS.fetch(frac)` instead which would raise an exception if the key doesn't exist, e.g. when attempting to call `format_fraction(1.2)` which results in a `frac` value of `1/5r`.

Comment: I was thinking of something like `FRACTIONS[frac] || format('%03i',frac*1000)`

Comment: @MarcRohloff I see, but in my case, a fraction that is neither a third nor a quarter would indeed be an error.

Comment: In that case I would prefer a more descriptive error like:
`FRACTIONS[frac] || raise "#{number} is not a valid fraction"`  you would also need to add `0/1r => ''` to your list

Comment: @MarcRohloff yes indeed, or `unless frac.zero?` beforehand.